# How to load a new version of the same java class at runtime?

Tags: java

If there is a class com.app.A  from JAR-1 loaded into the JVM then how can we load a new version of the same class com.app.A from another JAR-2 at runtime?

What are the different ways to do this?

-
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

One way is [OSGi](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363825/OSGi-for-Beginners). You can have multiple versions of the same bundle (jar) in an OSGi environment.

Say we have JAR-1 and JAR-2 in OSGi runtime exposing the same packages but different versions like this.

```
JAR-1 exports > org.home.code;version=1.0.0
JAR-2 exports > org.home.code;version=2.0.0
```

Now when some other jar needs `org.home.code` as a dependency, it can specify which version it needs.

You can find some popular OSGi implementations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi_Specification_Implementations).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**First:**
You can do it like it described here:

[Java ClassLoader: load same class twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804601/java-classloader-load-same-class-twice)

**Second:** You can just manually try to replace old `*.class` to new one. You can catch plenty of exceptions if you made significant changes, like added methods etc. I changed some logging, made some internal method refactoring and it worked for me.